# React Passing data to components

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent stateful component and i pass the state of show dialog to a stateless header component.
When a icon clicked on the header component it opens a stateless dialog component. 
In the stateless dialog component i want to be able to enter data into a text-field.
Do i have to completely change my code to make the stateless dialog to a stateful component?
Below is my code. If anyone can recommend the best way of doing this. Thanks.

```
class Layout extends Component {
    state = {
      show:false  
    }

    toggleSidenav = (action) =>{
        this.setState({
            showDialog:action
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Header
                    showNav={this.state.showDialog}
                    onHideNav={() => this.toggleSidenav(false)}
                    onOpenNav={() => this.toggleSidenav(true)}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }

}
export default Layout;
```

Header component

```
const Header = (props) => {
    console.log(props.onOpenNav)

    const navBars = () => (
        <div>
            <AppBar position="static">
                <Toolbar>
                    <IconButton color="inherit" aria-label="createfolder">
                        <SvgIcon>
                            <path d={createfolder}
                                 onClick={props.onOpenNav}
                                name="firstName" />
                        </SvgIcon>
                    </IconButton>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </div>
    )
    return (
        <div>
            <SideNav {...props} />
            <div>
                {navBars()}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Dialog Component

```
const DialogBox = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Dialog
                open={props.showNav}
                aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
                <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Add Folder</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    <TextField
                        margin="normal"
                    />
                </DialogContent>
                 <DialogActions>
              <Button onClick={props.onHideNav} color="primary">
              Cancel
      </Button>
          <Button onClick={props.onHideNav} color="primary"
              onChange={this.handleFieldChange}
              value={this.value}
             >
              Create
      </Button>
          </DialogActions>

            </Dialog>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You have to keep the input as state somewhere. It doesn't have to be in `DialogBox`, you can put it in a parent component and pass it to `DialogBox` via props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since component `Header` is readily stateful. You could initialize its state to

```
state = {
      show:false,
      formData: {}  //later, you may save user input from the child component here 
    }
```

and in `Header` component, you may add a function:

```
handleInputEntered = (event) => {
  const _data = { ...this.state.formData };
  _data[event.target.name] = event.target.value;

  this.setState({
    formData: _data
  });
}
```

and make sure to pass this new function as a prop to  like this:

```
<Header 
    handleInputEntered = {this.handleInputEntered}
    />
```

and set `onChange` to be this new function where you have input field:

```
<TextField
           onChange={this.props.handleInputEntered}     
                    />
```

It seems you're using `MaterialUI`, so just look up how you may supply the `onChange` property to TextField component.

Is this clear?

Comment: My layout component is stateful and my header component is a stateless component. Iam still abit confused

Comment: when i try and implement it doing something similar to what you are saying i get an error saying Unexpected use of 'name'  no-restricted-globals

Comment: Yes, your Header component is stateless. So when you pass a prop to <TextField />, you should write: `onChange={props.handleInputEntered} ` instead of `this.props.handleInputEntered`